# Alternative to Calendly that allows overlapping meetings at different locations?

Tags: web-apps

My company uses Calendly internally to schedule new hires for Orientation. We want to offer more location options but Calendly does not allow overlapping meetings at different locations. Is there an alternative that allows up to 6 events on the same date at the same time but in different locations? It's also essential that all events be on one single booking page.